# Updatepanel not working in upgraded webproject

Tags: .net-4.0, updatepanel, .net-1.1

I am working with an old web application originally developed in VB.NET 1.1. The application is now converted to the 4.0 framework and I wanted to use AJAX and the UpdatePanel. However I cannot get the UpdatePanel to work as expected. The page still does a full postback and not a partial postback as I would like it to do. If I do the same in a new application (not one converted from 1.1) it all works fine. I cannot find anything different between the two pages in terms of code and codebehind or references, obviously I am missing something. In the generated HTML for the two pages I do find differences, the page in the converted application for example does not have the following:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    //<![CDATA[ 
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ScriptManager1', 'form1',['tUpdatePanel1','UpdatePanel1'], [], [], 90, '');
    //]]>
```

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and resolved comparing the web.config of the two web application. One thing making update panels not to work, was the `xhtmlConformanceMode` setting. You can't use Legacy mode.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is not your answer, but a very strong recommendation (a friendly advice):

> Avoid UpdatePanels, please!

find another way to bring your application to AJAX.
Be sure that you will pay the cost at last (my experience), so pay it now.